# 2 legged oath request without command line

Tags: php, oauth, yql

i want to make an 2 legged oauth yql request with php.
So far:

```
// Include the PHP SDK.
include_once("yosdk/lib/Yahoo.inc");

// Define constants to store your API Key (Consumer Key) and
// Shared Secret (Consumer Secret).
define("API_KEY","her_comes the key");
define("SHARED_SECRET","here_comes_the_secret");

$two_legged_app = new YahooApplication(API_KEY,SHARED_SECRET);

$stock_query =  "elect * from ......";

$stockResponse = $two_legged_app->query($stock_query);
var_dump($stockrResponse);
```

But the problem is, that i dont want to query the command line..... i just want to oauth with the api key i got and use the url directly i got of the command when i typed in yql....

like this:

```
$url='http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20('+url_stocks+')&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys';
```

(i edited the url that came out my wishes for).Please dont ask why i dont use the command to query (long story). i would be pleased by getting some help.
thanks.

Comment: What's stopping you? What have you tried? What hasn't worked? What research have you done to solve this problem?

Comment: A: don't know exactly how to send the url as request do get an answer in a vaiable.What have i tried? A: just got succesfull with javascript but need know php....What hasn't worked? don't know exactly how to try... Research? A: yql documentation and google.But just getting command line examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it:

http://code.google.com/p/oauth-php/wiki/ConsumerHowTo

> include_once "oauth/library/OAuthStore.php";
>   include_once"oauth/library/OAuthRequester.php";
>
> > $key_1 = "your_key";  $secret_1 = "your_secret";
> >
> > $ticks="%22AAPL%22%2C%22MSFT%22";
> >
> > $options = array( 'consumer_key' => $key_1, 'consumer_secret' =>
> >     $secret_1 ); OAuthStore::instance("2Leg", $options );
> >
> > $url =
> >     "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20('$ticks')&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys";
> >     // this is the URL of the request $method = "GET"; // you can also use
> >     POST instead $params = null;
> >
> > try {
> >             // Obtain a request object for the request we want to make
> >             $request = new OAuthRequester($url, $method, $params);
> >             // Sign the request, perform a curl request and return the results, 
> >             // throws OAuthException2 exception on an error
> >             // $result is an array of the form: array ('code'=>int, 'headers'=>array(), 'body'=>string)
> >             $result = $request->doRequest();
> >
> > ```
> >     $response = $result['body'];
> >     $resp_array=json_decode($response,TRUE);
> >     echo $resp_array['query']['results']['quote'][1]['symbol']; // MSFT
> > ```
> >
> > } catch(OAuthException2 $e) { }